# Mac Numbers and Excel formula dealing with missing time?

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula

I have a sheet in numbers dealing with time. All values in the sheet are written as integers like 930 and 1700. I have to convert these to hours for payment purposes so first I have to convert them to time values. Simple enough.

```
=(TIME(LEFT(E,LEN(E)-2),RIGHT(E,2),)-TIME(LEFT(B,LEN(B)-2),RIGHT(B,2),))-(TIME(LEFT(D,LEN(D)-2),RIGHT(D,2),)-TIME(LEFT(C,LEN(C)-2),RIGHT(C,2),))
```

Table is:

```
Date    Time In    Lunch Start    Lunch End    Time Out    Total Hours
8/31    930        1230           1300         1700        7hr 30mins
9/1     930                                    1700        Error
```

This is how the table works with the data given and the formula above in col F. If there is a lunch, the formula works. If no lunch was taken, then the formula breaks because it's trying to convert the blank lunch cells.

How can I set the lunch calculation portion to ignore the lunch if there is none? Even putting 0 there will return an error because the length -2 can't find anything valid there. I don't know enough about numbers or excel to know but I assume it will need something like `IF C>0(...)` or something like that around the lunch calculation.

I included excel but I do not have excel. I'm sure it's easy enough to convert from an excel formula though so I really prefer something that will work in Mac Numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a simple if statement to check if lunch times were entered.

```
=if(and(C3="", D3=""),[calculate time from Time In to Time Out], [Your original formula])
```

The logic behind the statement is: `if([Condition], [Execute if True], [Execute if False])`